# Facebook videos and iPad compatibility

Tags: facebook, video, ipad, compatibility

I am developing an iPad application using Facebook Query Language. We can get the list of videos of an user along with its meta data by querying the table "video".  The meta data of the video are: video id, title, description, src, src_hq etc. 
Now, I want to play the Facebook video in my iPad using the URL given in the field src/src_hq.

1. What is the difference between these two attributes?
2. Do I get iPad compatible URL for all the videos. i.e. is it possible to play all the videos of Facebook in iPad including old videos uploaded.

If not possible, could you please give the objective-C sample code that embeds the video in HTML.

Regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure facebook videos are flv's and you'd need a flash player to play them. So to answer your question:

1. The `src`/`src_hq` fields are described in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video). The `src_hq` one is higher quality, most likely for the full-page type view, while the `src` one is likely used in streams and so on.
2. I doubt you will get a URL to a video that will work on the iPad. Probably not for new videos and probably not for 'old' videos either.

With that said -- try it! Query the table, get a video url, download it and see for yourself. Open it up in VLC or some-such and see what kind of video it is and get some details -- then post them here.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response.
I had uploaded an mp4 video to my account. When I tried to fetch my videos using Facebook Query Language, I could get it in mp4 format. 
If I upload flv video, do I get it in flv format itself?

Comment: I tried uploading flv videos also. I could get its mp4 video from Facebook Query Language.
Now, my question is dow we get mp4 video for videos uploaded long back.

Comment: flv is a container, not a video format itself, the point is that flv is normally played with a flash player. if you can get the mp4 out of the file supplied by facebook then you should be able to play it using normal iOS methods. see this, will require you to be signed in to the apple dev center: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798

Comment: and see here for what flv is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video, like I said in my answer, if you _don't_ get an flv out of facebook's API (and get an mp4 or whatever instead), then you should be fine to just play it normally.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I wanted to know whether I can be sure that I always get only mp4(quicktime supported) videos from Facebook so that I can play it in my iPad.

Comment: You seem to have confirmed already that uploading an flv (or any supported-by-facebook file type) yields that same filetype with their API. Thus the answer to your question is 'no', you can't be sure you can play videos on facebook on your iPad :/